# How could I implement a vector of stack?

Tags: c++, vector, stack

I am currently trying to implement a class with a vector of stacks. The class shall work as a stack to other objects but distribute the data to different stacks of a maximum size internally. If a stack is full a new one is created and pushed to the internal vector.

My current approach generates errors:

```
prog.cpp: In instantiation of ‘SetOfStack<T>::SetOfStack(int) [with T = int]’:
prog.cpp:54:32:   required from here
prog.cpp:13:17: error: no matching function for call to ‘std::vector<std::stack<int, std::deque<int, std::allocator<int> > >, std::allocator<std::stack<int, std::deque<int, std::allocator<int> > > > >::push_back(std::stack<int, std::deque<int, std::allocator<int> > >*)’
                 stacks.push_back( new stack<T> );
                 ^
/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/stl_vector.h:901:7: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘std::stack<int, std::deque<int, std::allocator<int> > >*’ to ‘const value_type& {aka const std::stack<int, std::deque<int, std::allocator<int> > >&}’
/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/stl_vector.h:919:7: note: void std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::push_back(std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::value_type&&) [with _Tp = std::stack<int, std::deque<int, std::allocator<int> > >; _Alloc = std::allocator<std::stack<int, std::deque<int, std::allocator<int> > > >; std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::value_type = std::stack<int, std::deque<int, std::allocator<int> > >]
       push_back(value_type&& __x)
       ^
/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/stl_vector.h:919:7: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘std::stack<int, std::deque<int, std::allocator<int> > >*’ to ‘std::vector<std::stack<int, std::deque<int, std::allocator<int> > >, std::allocator<std::stack<int, std::deque<int, std::allocator<int> > > > >::value_type&& {aka std::stack<int, std::deque<int, std::allocator<int> > >&&}’

prog.cpp: In instantiation of ‘void SetOfStack<T>::push(T) [with T = int]’:
prog.cpp:55:21:   required from here
prog.cpp:22:25: error: ‘__gnu_cxx::__alloc_traits<std::allocator<std::stack<int, std::deque<int, std::allocator<int> > > > >::value_type’ has no member named ‘push_back’
                         stacks[current_stack].push_back(new stack<T>);
                         ^

prog.cpp: In instantiation of ‘T SetOfStack<T>::pop() [with T = int]’:
prog.cpp:56:27:   required from here
prog.cpp:34:25: error: ‘__gnu_cxx::__alloc_traits<std::allocator<std::stack<int, std::deque<int, std::allocator<int> > > > >::value_type’ has no member named ‘pop_back’
                         stacks[current_stack].pop_back();
                         ^
```

Sample Code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stack>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

template <class T>
class SetOfStack {
public:
    SetOfStack( int max_size ): current_stack(0), max_stack_size(max_size) {
            stacks.reserve(10);
            stacks.push_back( new stack<T> );
    }

    ~SetOfStack() {
            stacks.clear();
    }       

    void push( T value ) {
            stacks[current_stack].push(value);
            if(stacks[current_stack].size() > max_stack_size) {
                    stacks[current_stack].push_back(new stack<T>);
                    current_stack++;
                    if(current_stack % 10 == 0 && current_stack > stacks.size()) {
                            stacks.reserve(stacks.size() + 10);
                    }
            }
    }

    T pop() {
            T value = stacks[current_stack].top();
            stacks[current_stack].pop();

            if(stacks[current_stack].size() == 0 && current_stack != 0 ) {
                    stacks[current_stack].pop_back();
                    current_stack--;
            }
    }

    T popAt( int index ) {
            T value = stacks[index].top();
            stacks[index].pop();
    }

private:
    int current_stack;
    int max_stack_size;
    vector< stack<T> > stacks;
};


int main() {
    // Test code
    SetOfStack<int> s_o_s(3);
    s_o_s.push(1);
    cout << s_o_s.pop() << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It looks like you have the general idea there, is something specifically not working with it? Couple comments: 1. In your `push` routine you are checking that `size() > max_stack_size`, you probably want `size() >= max_stack_size`. 2. Since you're calling `new stack<T>` in your `push` routine, you need to be calling `delete` in your `pop()` routine when you do `current_stack--`. You also need to `delete` everything in your `~SetOfStack()`

Comment: Oh, and your `pop()` looks like you forgot to `return value;`

Comment: Thanks for your comments. The error I get currently is `In instantiation of ‘SetOfStack<T>::SetOfStack(int) [with T = int]`, which is required from `stacks.push_back( new stack<T> );`.

Comment: And regarding the delete, does pop_back() not take care of that?! Or am I mistaken here. (sry, it has been some time since I last worked with C++ and STL )

Comment: Why do you want to do this? Isn't this already basically what `stack` does when backed by `deque` (which is the default)?

Comment: To be honest I am preparing for an test ( university related) and this is one of the mock questions I came up with. In a real project I would solve that in a different way of course.

Comment: What's the whole error message? You've only quoted the last line.

Comment: PS: Also I am curios what the error is about.

Comment: There you go: http://pastebin.com/0bKkEBWS

Comment: well... isn't vector<vector<T>> a stack of stacks? What keeps you from using vector as a stack? Also SetOfStack would imply set<stack<T>>, wouldn't it? Btw: You don't need naked new and delete (at least not in  this example)

Comment: you should post the error in the question, not in the comments. You can easily edit the question and add the error

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The error you're getting is this line:

```
stacks.push_back( new stack<T> );
```

As well as this line:

```
stacks[current_stack].push_back(new stack<T>);
```

Because you have declared stacks as a non-pointer:

```
vector< stack<T> > stacks;
```

So you want to use just `stack<T>()` instead of `new stack<T>`
Additionally, `std::stack` does not have a function `push_back`, you need to use `push` instead.

```
stacks.push_back(stack<T>());
stacks[current_stack].push(value);
```

As well as `pop` and not `pop_back()`:

```
stacks[current_stack].pop();
```

At which point, you no longer need the deletes I mentioned in my original comment, since it looks like you were not intending to call `new`

Comment: Both should be `stacks.push_back(stack<T>())` - in both cases the vector needs another stack. Or they could use `resize`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. You might be right, but now I get an error that vector has no sufficient candidate for `stacks.push_back( new stack<T> );`.

Comment: @Koogle for `vector` you use `push_back`, but for `stack` you use just `push`. @Alan corrected my answer, I was confused by the indexing into the vector and trying to push back!

Comment: A okay figured it out. The `new` in `push_back` is unnecessary.